# Why does PIE have form *dʰwey- / *dʰew- / dʰeubʰ- without initial (s)?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Why does Proto-Indo-European have form *dʰwey- / *dʰew- / dʰeubʰ-  (I don't know which is correct) despite of the fact that Proto-Germanic has "s mobile" (compare English **s**team)?
Is it OK that Proto-Germanic "t" matches Proto-Indo-European "dʰ"?
https://etymologeek.com/eng/steam
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/steam#Etymology
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/staumaz

Comment: Lower on your page you have a list of other descendants which do begin with "d".

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry but I don't understand you. Which page do you mean?

Comment: Your first link.

Answer (score 2):

I would've thought if 'steam' were to be given an IE etymology without an s-mobile a better source would be *dʰewh₂-[1] (smoke, mist, haze). 
See: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0ewh%E2%82%82-